# Find a increasing function $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f\leq g$ and $f'\leq g$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let  $f,f':\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$.

Asumme that $\lim_{n\to+\infty}{f(n)}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}{f'(n)}=+\infty$

I want to find a increasing function $g:\mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ such that $f\leq g$ and $f'\leq g$. Where $\mathbb{N}$ are naturals numbers.

A suggestion How find $g$, thanks much.

Comment: If you assume $f(n)\geq f'(n)$ for some $n$, can you see some value that would function for $g(n)$? What if $f'(n)\geq f(n)$?

Answer (score 0):

$f''(n)=f(n)+f'(n)$, and $h(n)=\max_{k\in \{0,\ldots,n\}}f''(k)$.
For $n\in \Bbb N$, we have $\{0,\ldots,n\}\subset \{0,\ldots,n,n+1\}$, hence 
$h(n)=\max_{k\in \{0,\ldots,n\}}f''(k)\leq \max_{k\in \{0,\ldots,n,n+1\}}f''(k)=h(n+1)$.
We have also $f\leq f''\leq h$ and  $f'\leq f''\leq h$.

Answer (score 0):

If $f,f':\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be two any functions, define
$$g(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n (f(i)+f'(i)),$$
then obvious that $g$ is an increasing function such that $f\leq g$ and  $f'\leq g$.